what is the source of this noise when recording to raspberry pi using USB soundcard
I connect aux out from my laptop to USB soundcard mic in and use arecord to record audio. But I am getting noise even recording at CD quality. The nature of the noise is really strange as it seems to vary with the sound. To understand the noise better I played a 440 Hz sinewave and a 200 Hz sinewave to see if the noise remains the same, strangely enough it doesn't. Here is what it looks like .
There is no noise using the same USB soundcard and recording to laptop



Can you show the recorded waveform? Is there clipping?

The spectrum indicates the audio output voltage is too high for the recording device audio input and it clips, as the spectrum almost resembles the spectrum of a square wave. You can verify it from the waveform.

+1 There seemed to be a strong correlation between between output frequency and its gain whenever OP was playing said frequency.

Great observation, a stupid mistake by me, I didn't notice the volume was too high.
